# Your total DEV@Cloud disk usage is over your subscription's quota

Tags: cloudbees

I have one jenkins job.

My first configuration stores the last 60 builds.

After 32 builds I get following message:

Build execution is suspended due to the following reason(s):

Your total DEV@Cloud disk usage is over your subscription's quota. Your subscription Free allows 2 GB, but you are using 2052 MB across all services (Forge and Jenkins). To fix this, you can either upgrade your subscription or delete some data in your Forge repositories, Jenkins workspaces or build artifacts.
Ok, the build artefacts are to big.
Now I configured the jenkins job to store 60builds and only 3 artefacts.

Where can I find the (old) build artefacts?
Where can I delete them?

Comment: changing the builds/artifacts retention strategy is the way to go to reduce disk usage. To unlock your account, you have to delete some old builds from your job history. Disk quota computation won't occur immediately anyway

Answer (score 2):

You can manually delete build artifacts by deleting builds. This can be achieved by selecting a build from build history and then deleting it with the "delete this build" link. This is quite cumbersome, so a better solution is to go to build config and do the following: check the "discard old builds" checkbox, click "Advanced" button, put a suitable value to either the "days to keep artifacts" or "max # of builds to keep with artifacts".

You could also install the disk usage plugin, which gives you information on how much space your jobs are taking.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [wiki article about managing disk usage on DEV@cloud](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/DiskUsage).